# Can we make the logo a little bigger on the Stack Overflow hoodie?

Tags: feature-request, logo, shop

I recently bought a [Stack Overflow Hoodie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-overflow-hoodie). When I bought it, I expected the logo to be a little bigger....

It's a $30 sweatshirt with a logo on it that is barely 3 inches wide, and about half an inch tall.
[image: Stack Overflow hoodie logo]

I like the hoodie. It's comfortable, and I am happy to support Stack Exchange by buying their products. However, it would be nice if I was able to show it off, i.e., have a logo on it that is big enough for someone who is not *looking for it* to notice it, and it would also be nice if we could put something on the back as well.

That might be the right size logo to put on a polo shirt, but it is way to small for a hoodie.

I know Stack Exchange probably has a lot of them and that they would have to sell them before starting to make new ones, but, at some point, can we please make the logo big enough to be visible?

Comment: An *inch*?  I've seen them in person, they're much larger than an inch wide...

Comment: I just measured, it's actually about 3 inches - which is still really small.

Comment: Ok *that's* more like it, just sounded like an extreme exaggeration to me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate - [How can I make people jealous of my swag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132140/can-we-make-the-logo-a-little-bigger-on-the-stackoverflow-hoodie)

Comment: This is ironic because "make the logo bigger!" is a classic client ask (and source of frustration) for web developers.

Comment: @Lix: The disadvantage of multi-tab browsing: I clicked that link three times before figuring out what's going on...

Comment: I want it in black with the logo text in white o0

Comment: Why, that logo is 12 inches long!

Comment: @Won't - what are you talking about? I put a tape measure right underneath it. It's 3 inches - not 12... a 12 inch logo would practically take up the entire width of the hoodie (which I actually wouldn't mind, if it was on the back...)

Comment: @Ephraim: Dude, shaddup, there might be girls reading this.

Comment: @Scott We can use the Make My Logo Bigger Cream! http://www.makemylogobiggercream.com/